# Keyboard shortcut for Google Image Search text input box when using Chrome on OSX

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-image-search, osx

While searching for images using text input, I want to be able to go from an existing google image search to the input box using keyboard shortcuts. I'm using Google Chrome on OSX.

A [2012 answer by frozenkoi](https://superuser.com/a/410934) on SuperUser, in response to a question about google search for web pages (not images), talks about using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, but these shortcuts don't even work on Google Chrome on OSX for Google web search, let alone Google image search.

<kbd>F6</kbd>, mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/410831/885), doesn't work even when doing Google web search. I tried with and without <kbd>fn</kbd>, and making function buttons the default and not.

Rather than going straight to the input box, I can go the address bar and type in "images.google.com.au [search term]", as suggested by [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en&visit_id=1-636309472039121540-1477481639&rd=1) but that's a little awkward.

Another possibility is to set image search as your default search engine temporarily.

I'm asking here rather than on superuser, because a question about Google web search in 2014 got closed as [off-topic](https://superuser.com/questions/852646/are-there-any-keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-google-search-page?noredirect=1&lq=1).